# Expected field value does not appear after converting .shp to .asc

Tags: qgis

I converted .shp map to .asc choosing land-use type field (e.g building=1 etc). I expected the .asc will contain numbers of the land-use types. However, the values are all zero when I open it with notepad. Below the parameters used for converting .shp to raster and raster to .asc.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the values in the raster file?

Comment: Yes, there should be values of the chosen field in the file right? Or it is not?

Comment: Have you checked?

Comment: Yes, I open with notepad and there is nothing but zero. There should be other values than zero such 1,2..9 which are land-use types.

Comment: Well, have you simply loaded the raster in QGIS and checked there? And does the cell size correspond with the feature size of the shapefile?

Comment: I loaded it and nothing appeared. I had done it in Arcmap and the result is only 1 file .asc. But here I found three files with ..asc.aux.xml and .prj as additional files. I need this .asc file with the value of the certain field to be used in Netlogo. I am totally beginner to GIS.

Comment: I am asking specifically about the raster data, not the `.asc`. In order to realize which step is faulty, you need to know, whether the rasterize step works properly or not.

Comment: I loaded the raster file and I don't see chosen field value there. I am sorry, how do I know if the cell size correspond with the feature size?

Comment: You set the raster size to 30 x 30 m (5th and 6th row in the dialogue) - and you can simply measure the size of your features.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean by "..simply measure the size...". Is the raster size important? I thought it can be any number..

Comment: You know you can measure distances in QGIS, right?

Comment: Yes I think, but I still cannot link "cell size" and "measure distance" in what I am doing..sorry for my poor knowledge..
I had done this in Arcmap and all was already set up so I expected similar things in QGIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used SAGA>Raster creation tools>Rasterize for .shp to raster and
Vector>Conversion>Translate for raster to ascii. This solved my problem.